# Why is a storyboard popover segue appearing on a subsequent view within a navigation controller

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue

this is odd, but I'll try to explain the best I can.

I have a navigation controller which has a view.  The view asks a simple question.  That view then has two segues available -- one on the view for a correct answer, which is a "show" on the navigation controller and the other for an incorrect answer which is a "popover".

The segues are tied to the view and the answer box for the show and popover respectively.

I'm testing the answer on button press and using performSegueWithIdentifier to then show the appropriate window.

```
if (answerField.text == "2") {
        println("Correct")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Correct", sender: sender)
    } else {
        println("Incorrect")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Error", sender: sender)
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that if I get the answer correct, it moves fine to the next view, but it shows the "incorrect" popover view after segueing to the correct one.

I know that sounds complicated, but it's a super simple app at present.  I suspect I'm just doing it wrong.  Of note is that I also get an error "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged" which may be related.

Many thanks for any assistance anyone can provide.
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have one or both of the segues hooked up directly to the button in your storyboard, which will trigger the segue automatically on the button press even when you don't call `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:)` in code. You are then setting up an `IBAction` method which is *also* called on the button press, where you are then programmatically performing the segue *again*.

You can check this by going to your storyboard and selecting the button. Go to the connections inspector on the right, and I expect you'll see a `Triggered Segues` section, with an "action" triggering your "show" segue. You can remove this by clicking the cross next to the connection.

For segues that should be initiated programmatically, you should create a segue by dragging from the view controller object (rather from a control / actionable element) to the next view controller. This will create a generic segue that is only triggered by `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:)` in code.

As you have noticed, since your segue is for a popover presentation it will complain unless it is explicitly anchored to a particular view in your storyboard. You can still drag the segue from the view controller object to the popover view controller, but you must manually hook up the anchor: select the segue in the storyboard, choose the attributes inspector on the right, and drag from the circle in the "Anchor" field to the text field you want to anchor to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  That's a great answer and I checked, but that was not the case in this instance.  I have the segue tied to the text field because if I don't, it complains that a popover segue must have an anchor.  However, if I have another label with 0 alpha right next to it, this seems to fix it as the segue was a Triggered Segue for the text field.  I assume there must be a better way than having a hidden text field though to get an anchor?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Darren It sounds like my assumption was correct (you say the segue _was_ a triggered segue for the text field). Popovers are quite particular about being anchored to a view in a storyboard, but you can still create a popover segue without having it implicitly triggered from a particular UI element. I've updated my answer to explain how.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.  I knew I must be doing something wrong.  Thankyou so much.